# Custom Data Annotation isn't Displaying Error Message

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-annotations

I'm making a custom data annotation and I'm doing some testing, I can't figure out why it doesn't display my error message.

**PersonInfo.cs**

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(AWValidation), "ValidateName")]
public String GivenName { get; set; }
```

**AWValidation.cs**

```
    public static ValidationResult ValidateName(String name)
    {
        // Perform validation logic here and set isValid to true or false.

        if (name != null)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(
                "The name for this customer does not match the required criteria.");
        }
    }
```

It enters ValidationResult ValidateName(String name) only when the users clicks the save button, although it doesn't display the ValidationResult, it displays its default error message.

What I want is when the user tabs out or loses focus of the GivenName textbox to display my custom data annotation.

My co-worker told me this might be caused because it's validating the server side GivenName, and I need to make it validate the client side? Although I don't understand why

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="This is a required value")]
public String GivenName { get; set; }
```

displays when I lose focus/tab out of the GivenName textbox.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Jason :)
(P.S I'm using MVVM)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968542/use-client-side-validation-when-custom-required-attribute-is-used/12968598#12968598  I think this is what you need

Comment: I dont know if you are using wpf/silverlight but if you try to rename AWValidation.cs to AWValidation.shared.cs. In WCF RIA services it would copy that validator to the client side. But i'm uncertain about WPF.